# Can I use the Thalys lounge at Bruxelles Midi with a DB first-class ticket?

Tags: brussels, train-stations, thalys

My connection at Bruxelles-Midi station was delayed. I am in possession of a DB first-class ticket to join an outbound ICE service.

Am I eligible to use the Thalys lounge while I await the connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Thalys homepage](https://www.thalys.com/de/en/offers-and-fares/flex) says that:

> You have access to the Thalys Lounges for a pleasant experience
>   **before or after your journey**.

As I understand this, you cannot use your DB ticket to access the lounge. You only have access to it if you arrive in Brussels on a premium ticket.

Comment: Apparently, DB customers can in some instances use the lounge, but only when they also possess a BahnCard.